# When resizing window layout isn't correct

Tags: jquery, css

```js
$(function() {
  var pull = $('#pull');
  menu = $('nav ul');
  menuHeight = menu.height();

  $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
  });


});

$(window).resize(function() {
  var w = $(window).width();
  menuHeight = menu.height();
  menu = $('nav ul');
  if (w > 704 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
    menu.removeAttr('style');
  }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var w = $(window).width();
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0 && w < 704) {
    $('nav ul').slideUp();
  } else {
    $('nav ul').slideDown();
    menu.removeAttr('style');
  }
});

function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('.menu_sticky').offset().top;
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (window_top > div_top && width < 764) {
    $('.menu').addClass('stick');
  } else {
    $('.menu').removeClass('stick');
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.right-side {
  /*border: 1px solid  #ccc; */
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 0em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;
}
.left-side {
  /*border: 1px solid  #ccc;  */
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0em;
  margin-right: 0em;
  margin-left: 0em;
  font-family: 'Unica One', cursive;
  /*font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;*/
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  /*font-family: 'Unica One', cursive;*/
}
.left-side::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.logo img {
  height: auto !important;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.lang {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.title {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  color: #606062;
}
.orange_title {
  color: #f58634;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}
.orange_title:first-child {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}
.delimiter {
  float: left;
  background-image: url(../graphics/wood_bg_1.jpg);
  background-repeat: x-repeat;
  background-position: bottom left;
  height: 3em;
  width: 100%;
}
/* MENU */

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 10000;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 3em;
  width: 100%;
}
nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
nav li a {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav li ul {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  /*Animation*/
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 1s ease;
  -o-transition: height 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: height 1s ease;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}
.dropdown:hover ul {
  height: 186px;
}
nav li ul li {
  margin: 0;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #f58634;
}
nav li ul li a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
nav li ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a#pull {
  display: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #606062;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
/* END MENU */




/* MEDIA QUERIES */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  nav {
    padding-left: 0em;
  }
  nav li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E7E8;
  }
  nav li ul li a .grey_container_text {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0em;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E7E8;
  }
  nav li ul li a nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav a#pull {
    display: block;
    background-color: #E6E7E8;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0.3em;
    height: 2.2em;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a#pull:after {
    content: "";
    background: url("../graphics/menu_icon.png") no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.9em;
    top: 0.6em;
  }
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
}
/* max-width 720px */

@media screen and (max-width: 45em) {
  nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0em;
  }
  .left-side {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .logo img {
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
  }
  .lang {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  nav {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E7E8;
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  nav li ul li a {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  nav a#pull {
    display: block;
    background-color: #E6E7E8;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0.3em;
    height: 2.2em;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a#pull:after {
    content: "";
    background: url("../graphics/menu_icon.png") no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.9em;
    top: 0.6em;
  }
  .columns-container {
    float: left;
  }
  .right-side {
    float: left;
  }
  .kolekcije_thumb {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0em;
  }
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
}
/* min-width 721px and max-width 1024px */

@media only screen and (min-width: 45.063em) and (max-width: 64em) {
  .left-side {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 16.5em;
    margin-right: -17.75em;
    float: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  nav li a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  nav li ul li a {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  .logo img {
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .right-side {
    margin-left: 16.7em;
    float: right;
  }
  .kolekcije_thumb {
    width: 48%;
    /* width:calc(100% / 3); */
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  .lang {
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
}
/* min-width 1025px and max-width 1440px */

@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) and (max-width: 90em) {
  .left-side {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 19.5em;
    margin-right: -22.75em;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
  }
  nav li a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  nav li ul li a {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  .right-side {
    margin-left: 19.7em;
    float: left;
  }
}
/* min-width 1441px and max-width 1920px */

@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) and (max-width: 120em) {
  .left-side {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 21.5em;
    margin-right: -22.75em;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
  }
  nav li a {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  nav li ul li a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .right-side {
    margin-left: 21.7em;
    float: left;
  }
}
/* min-width 1921px */

@media only screen and (min-width: 120.063em) {
  .left-side {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 27.5em;
    margin-right: -28.75em;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
  }
  nav li a {
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
  nav li ul li a {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  .right-side {
    margin-left: 27.7em;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns-container">

  <div class="left-side">

    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="./graphics/logo.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_sticky">
      <div class="menu">
        <nav class="clearfix">
          <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a> 
          <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">menu item 3</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </nav>
      </div>
      <!-- end menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- end menu_sticky -->
  </div>
  <!-- end left-side -->

  <div class="right-side">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
    sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
    Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
    Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
    Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla
    mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
    sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
    Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
    Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
    Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla
    mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
    penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo,
    rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend
    ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam
    rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien
    ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
    sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
    Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
    Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
    Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla
    mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</br>
  </div>
```

i have written this code `jsfiddle.net/7pf4g7dg/5/` i now i have two problems.

1)Shrink Result window (link) less than 720px. Scroll down a bit. Resize result tab wider than 720px. Menu is 100% (which i don't want), than scroll down/up a bit and everything is the way i want it. Question: how can i fix this, so that menu isn't 100% but normal size?

2)With Result window wider (link) than 720px scroll down a bit and than resize it down (smaller than 720px). Problem: No menu is visible on top of page, but when you scroll down/up a bit menu appears. I want that menu appears even if you don't srcoll.

I hope you understand what i want to achieve.

Regards ML.

Comment: Don't just link to JSFiddle - actually post your code in the question!

Comment: Code extends max lines so i can't post all of it...

Comment: Get rid of all the lorem ipsum and it should fit. And perhaps cut out some CSS that isn't purely necessary.